# How can I query total pay as student id?

Tags: php

Query as student id and show it as total pay. I was post before about this problem. maybe I was not able to clear my question.so I post it again.
please help me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuYwb.jpg

```html
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name


// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

?>


<?php
$sql0="SELECT * FROM payment as std_id GROUP BY std_id ";
$sql="SELECT SUM(pay) FROM payment as std_id GROUP BY std_id ";
$result0=mysql_query($sql0);
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>






<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="6"><div align="center"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>std id</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>pay</strong></td>



<?php
while($rows0=mysql_fetch_array($result0))  {
?>

<tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
?>

<td><?php echo $rows0['std_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['SUM(pay)']; ?></td>



</tr>

<?php
}
}
?>



</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>




<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

I am new here.I was post this problem before. but was not able to clear my question. please help me.

Comment: Is it the answer or question? :)

Comment: What's the existing mysql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Here you need to get amount Student wise, so need to do `GROUP BY` student & also want sum amount, so need to call `SUM` function and pass amount in it.

Here is MySQL Query:

```
SELECT std_id AS studentid , SUM(pay) as Amount 
FROM table 
GROUP BY std_id;
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

use following query.

```
select studentID,sum(pay) from tableName  group by studentId;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT std_id, sum(pay) AS total_payment FROM table_name GROUP BY std_id
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
select std_id,sum(pay) as total from payment group by std_id
```