# how can I show 2tabile data in a table by sum

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show some data from 2 table to 1 table. and 1 table's column will be sum as student id.

finally all data will show as student id 
please see this image for clear my question. PLS help.

[image]

```html
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="workshop_all"; // Database name


// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

?>


<?php


$sqlnew="SELECT std_id, sum(pay) AS pay FROM payment GROUP BY std_id";
$resultnew=mysql_query($sqlnew);



?>






<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="6"><div align="center"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </div></td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td align="center"><strong>std id</strong></td>

<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>pay</strong></td>




<tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultnew))  {
?>

<td><?php echo $rows['std_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['pay']; ?></td>



</tr>

<?php
}

?>



</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>




<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Why you ask same question again & again ?? You just ask it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653950/how-can-i-query-total-pay-as-student-id/27654573

Comment: man this is the very basic principle of joining, please try researching  before you post questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the join in query like bellow

```
//change TABLE1 TO your table name

$sqlnew="SELECT p.std_id, sum(p.pay) AS pay,t1.email FROM payment p LEFT JOIN TABLE1 as t1 ON(t1.id=p.std_id) GROUP BY p.std_id";
$resultnew=mysql_query($sqlnew);
```

**change the join type as per your requirement. the above query for only example**

- INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH
  tables
- LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows
  from the right table
- RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched
  rows from the left table
- FULL JOIN: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

**more about join [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)** 
**AND also check this http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/**

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Join like so :

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.email, sum(t2.pay) as pay FROMTable1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2. std_id
GROUP BY t1.id, t2.email
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.std_id, t1.email, sum(t2.pay) as pay  
from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.std_id group by t2.std_id
```